# How do I deal with unlimited loop problems?

Tags: python

so i have this code

```
pa=""
newpa=""
use=''
use=input('enter username:')
pa=input('enter password')
while True:
    if len(pa)==12:
        newpa=input('re-enter password:') 
    else:
        print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')
    if newpa==pa:
        print('you have successfully created a new account!')
```

whenever I insert a pa that's incorrect the else print keeps looping. How do I make it so whenever I enter a pa that doesn't meet the if to loop back to newpa
if this help this is my algorithm [alogrythm of what I am trying to go for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dte1W.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code example. But it seems you have to ask for the input of `pa` again in the loop if `pa` doesn't meet the requirements. And of course you need to `break` from the loop if all checks were succesful.

Comment: Since noone mentioned it yet: You don't have to define `pa`, `newpa` and `use` as empty strings at the start of your program. `input` will overwrite those entries anyway. And please think about using more readable names. You don't win anything if you shorten the variable for the name of the user to `use` and password to `pa`.  The program won't run any faster if you shorten the names. You just confuse yourself and other readers of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be the put the **input** statement inside the **while** loop. At the moment your code loops back to the top of the while loop without giving the user a chance to re-enter their password.

You'll also want to move the check for the re-entry part so that it only executes if the first password was valid. And let the user know if their passwords didn't match.

Finally, you'll want to break the loop when a valid password is entered and verified. Use **break** for this.

The final code would look like this:

```
pa=""
newpa=""
use=''
use=input('enter username:')
while True:

    pa=input('enter password')

    if len(pa)==12:
        newpa=input('re-enter password:')
        if newpa==pa:
            print('you have successfully created a new account!')
            break
        else:
            print('the passwords did not match!')
    else:
        print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')
```

Hope that helps and makes sense!

Comment: This is very useful, however, I want to give the user an infinite amount of chances to re-enter the password if it doesn't meet the if value

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will run continuously until you add `break` statement.

You can try something like below,

```
pa=""
newpa=""
use=''
use=input('enter username:')

while True:

   pa=input('enter password')

   if len(pa)==12:
      newpa=input('re-enter password:')
      if newpa==pa:
       print('you have successfully created a new account!')
       break

   else:
      print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in the last `if` you want to exit from loop. So, add `break` after print.

```
if newpa==pa: 
    print('you have successfully created a new account!')
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while True` loop and break from that loop if the password meets the requirements. Then you can enter the password a second time and compare if both inputs match.

```
username = input('enter username:')
while True:
    password = input('enter password')
    if len(password) == 12  and password.isdigit():
        break
    print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')

password_check = input('re-enter password:')
if password == password_check:
    print('you have successfully created a new account!')
```

You might want to wrap that in an additional loop if the passwords don't match.

---

If you use functions you can reduce the complexity of the main part.

```
def enter_password(message):
    while True:
        password = input(message)
        if len(password) == 12 and password.isdigit():
            break
        print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')
    return password


def main():
    username = input('enter username:')
    while True:
        password = enter_password('enter password')
        password_match = enter_password('re-enter password')
        if password == password_match:
            break
        print("The passwords don't match.")

    print('you have successfully created a new account!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use break to break the statement and continue to continue the loop statement according to your requirement. I hope the following code meets your requirement. Thanks and let me know if there's anything I can help with.

```
user=input('enter username:')

while True:
    pa=input('enter password:')
    if len(pa)==12:
        newpa=input('re-enter password:')
        while newpa!=pa:
            newpa=input('re-enter password:')
    else:
        print('the password used did not meet our system requirements, please enter a 12 digit password')
        continue;
    
    if (newpa==pa):
        print('you have successfully created a new account!')
        break;
```